# Receiving "missing FROM-clause" Programming error in django query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I am trying to write a query, that retrieves all subscriptions whose owners should be notified about it's expiry.

I would like to exclude the already notified subscriptions and subscriptions that have a newer subscription available.

The query is next:

```
Subscription.objects.filter(
    end_date__gte=timezone.now(),
    end_date__lte=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14),
).exclude(
    Q(notifications__type=Notification.AUTORENEWAL_IN_14) | Q(device__subscriptions__start_date__gt=F('start_date'))
)
```

Without the `| Q(device__subscriptions__start_date__gt=F('start_date')` part, the query works perfectly. With it, django (postgres) raises the next error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "u1"
LINE 1: ...ption" U0 INNER JOIN "orders_subscription" U2 ON (U1."id" = ...
```

I checked the sql and it seems incorrect:

```
SELECT "orders_subscription"."id",
       "orders_subscription"."months",
       "orders_subscription"."end_date",
       "orders_subscription"."start_date",
       "orders_subscription"."order_id",
       "orders_subscription"."device_id",
FROM "orders_subscription"
WHERE ("orders_subscription"."churned" = false
       AND "orders_subscription"."end_date" >= '2019-04-05T13:27:39.808393+00:00'::timestamptz
       AND "orders_subscription"."end_date" <= '2019-04-19T13:27:39.808412+00:00'::timestamptz
       AND NOT (("orders_subscription"."id" IN
                   (SELECT U1."subscription_id"
                    FROM "notifications_notification" U1
                    WHERE (U1."type" = 'AUTORENEWAL_IN_2W'
                           AND U1."subscription_id" IS NOT NULL))
                 OR ("orders_subscription"."device_id" IN
                       (SELECT U2."device_id"
                        FROM "orders_subscription" U0
                        INNER JOIN "orders_subscription" U2 ON (U1."id" = U2."device_id")
                        WHERE (U2."start_date" > (U0."start_date")
                               AND U2."device_id" IS NOT NULL))
                     AND "orders_subscription"."device_id" IS NOT NULL)))) LIMIT 21

Execution time: 0.030680s [Database: default]
```

This is the part that is causing the issue:

```
INNER JOIN "orders_subscription" U2 ON (U1."id" = U2."device_id")
 WHERE (U2."start_date" > (U0."start_date")
                               AND U2."device_id" IS NOT NULL))
```

U1 is not defined anywhere (it is locally in the other clause, but that doesn't matter.

The relational model is quite simple, a device can have many subscriptions, a subscription can have many (different) notifications.

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="subscriptions")
    # Other non significatn fields

class Device(models.Model):
    # No relational fields

class Notification(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey('orders.Subscription', related_name="notifications", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # Other non significatn fields
```

So my question is: is my query wrong or is it a bug in Django ORM query generator?

Comment: post your model

Comment: Can you share Django version?

Comment: `U1` isn't available in the portion that you mentioned as the problem area. You'd need to find a way to join `notifications_notification` in the second query.

Comment: @c.grey I added the model in the bottom.

Comment: @Karioki Django version is 2.1.3

Comment: @JSpratt notifications_notification, shouldn't be in the second query as they are completely separated. The first part of the query is perfectly OK, the second one is missing U1 (which is not in any way connected with U1 from the first). I should have deleted the notifications part of the query before posting, as it has no influence on the bad formatting of the second part, my bad.

Comment: I'm just saying you have this portion `INNER JOIN "orders_subscription" U2 ON (U1."id" = U2."device_id")` where `U1.id` does not exist in the query. That's what is causing the error. It's saying you're missing a `FROM` for `U1`. It should probably be `U0."id"`. Been a while since I've used Django but should `device__subscriptions__start_date__gt` be `device__orders_subscription__start_date__gt`?

Comment: Django is just joining the wrong table. I think you can do it by switching `device__subscriptions` to `subscriptions__device`. Couldn't edit my last comment anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ORM clearly fails in translating your clause into SQL. It happens even when the clause is used in isolation (without the preceding clause, i.e. without a `U1` alias anywhere in the query).

Apart from the non-existing alias, the ORM also seems to misidentify the origin of `F('start_date')` – it is the main `orders_subscription` (the one without an alias), not any aliased table from a subselect.

You can lend the ORM a hand by defining a proper subquery yourself.

(The attempts below are based on the assumption that the intent of the clause is to exclude subscriptions that have sibling subscriptions (= same parent device) with later dates.)

So here's the exclude filter with the corrected clause:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

qs.exclude(
    Q(notifications__type=Notification.AUTORENEWAL_IN_14) |
    Q(device_id__in=Subquery(Subscription.objects
        .filter(
            device_id=OuterRef('device_id'), 
            start_date__gt=OuterRef('start_date'))
        .values('device_id')
    ))
)
```

However, looking at the filter more closely, we are selecting a column (`device_id`) whose value we have just passed as a filter condition. This is better expressed by an [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) subquery:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

(qs.annotate(has_younger_siblings=Exists(Subscription.objects.filter(
            device_id=OuterRef('device_id'), 
            start_date__gt=OuterRef('start_date'))))
  .exclude(has_younger_siblings=True)
  .exclude(notifications__type=Notification.AUTORENEWAL_IN_14)
)
```